# PhoneGap native popups

Tags: ios, knockout.js, cordova

I'm building an app using PhoneGap 2.9.0 as well as utilizing KnockoutJS. This is, essentially, a phonebook app.

When clicking on the name of the entry to display deeper data there is, among other things, phone number, name, location, etc. I've constructed the necessary links to get email and phone to work natively ... as well as the native iOS popups for "Add to Contacts / Copy" and such.

Those work just fine and as expected. My question lies in how to enable those same popup menus for non-link items such as NAME / LOCATION where I want the native popup to display for COPY / ADD TO CONTACTS.

My first thought was to create it as a link as well, which works fine except there is an OPEN option that I do not want there.

Obviously I can create my own popup, but I wanted to build it so the native one pops up. Ideas?

Comment: ok, so you want to use your phones popup messages?

Comment: yes, the native ones that popup when clicking a link such as call/email